# bash parameter substitute digit one or more times

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I have a version string, for example

```
version=1.2.23b2
```

I want to have only the last part with the `b2`, so I tried this:

```
${version##*[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*}
```

My thought was that `*` would mean no or many repetitions of the leading pattern, but in fact it means any character no or many times. So I want my pattern to express, that this is only about digits, one ore more times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` in glob pattern matches any character 0 or more times.

You can use extended glob pattern here:

```
shopt -s extglob 
echo "${version##+([0-9.])}"
b2
```

Or else, you can use regex here:

```
version='1.2.23b2'
re='^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(.+)'
[[ $version =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

b2
```

Even this regex should work above:

```
re='^[0-9.]+(.+)'
```